# How to do lazy loading of Blazer application made in ABP framework

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, abp

We have built an application with ABP framework and Blazor with a very high opening time. The first page of the application takes about 1-2 minutes to load, and the application size is about 24.98 MB. We are trying a modular approach. But the app's loading time has been a concern for us. How can we optimise this application while reducing its loading time? We have learned about lazy loading in Blazor. But since many DLLs are associated with the ABP framework, we are confused about how we can apply lazy loading here—looking for expert opinion or advice on this matter.

[image: Application loading]

Comment: You should probably ask that to ABP framework's support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading is not recommended in general, and specifically in abp, check this link: [Lazy-loading abp suite](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/11456)

Now, regarding the long load time, if you have identity server, be sure to enable redis and connect to it correctly, and also check if this is only when first loaded, any subsequent refreshes take the same time? If not, try to publish a release (non-develompent) and test if it takes the same time, maybe you also need to check if your landing page can be on a CDN?